# Window stuck out side desktop

Tags: 12.04, window-manager

one of my windows is stuck out side the desktop area. I can see a bit of it but cannot see enough to to drag it back. Anyone know another way to move it ?

[image: window partiality outside desktop]

As you can see I cant get to the left side or top of the window please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, drag the window with the left mouse button. It doesn't matter where within the window you click -- you will always be able to drag it. Actually, this is so much more convenient that aiming for the window decoration that I always use it.

Likewise, with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging with the *second* mouse button you can resize the window through clicking anywhere within it.

Furthermore, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and use the cursor keys to first select the "Move" option and then to move the window.